# Do I have to be careful if installing ubuntu on hdd with Win 8?

Tags: installation, dual-boot, windows

I have here a new system with win 8 RTM (Release to Manufacturers). Im not really working on windows, but I have to use this pc. There is another free partition so I could install ubuntu 12.04. I did this always with a win vista/7 system and then people can dualboot.

Now do I have to be careful with win 8? Or am I doing the same stuff as I did it on a win 7 hdd?

Comment: You should always be careful when you're altering the system configuration and partitions. Apart from that I don't think that you should run into troubles with your specific demand. Just make sure to use the correct partition for your installation.

Comment: What about the UEFI secure boot that supposed to block users from dual booting? any successful installs with win8?

Comment: Oh right, UEFI secure...thats not good.

Answer (score 0):

you can also read this thread : http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2055842

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.